# Deleting old rows on the same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a delete query that removes old records from the DB based on the date, but the issue is there could be multiple records for the same day and I just need to keep the most recent one.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    ItemName,
    1_PRICE,
    1_STOCK,
    2_STOCK,
    updated
FROM
    inventory 
WHERE
    ItemName = "24T7351" 
ORDER BY 
    updated DESC
```

Here's the SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb0a3d/1

So basically what I want is a query that returns all records grouped by day except the most recent one for each day.

Pseudo code:
    select *
    group by updated
    order by desc
    keep the first row for each day
    delete the rest for each day

Comment: your where clause uses item name. do you mean all items on the day with the item name?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane No sorry, it was just to test a single item from a huge table.

Comment: What if two rows are uptated within one second? Which one do you want to keep?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Always the latest for the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
DELETE FROM inventory
WHERE updated NOT IN (
    SELECT updated FROM (
        SELECT MAX(updated) updated
        FROM inventory
        GROUP BY DATE(updated)
    ) i
)
```

This would work well if you have the `updated` indexed (ordered).

Basically the sub query gets all the max updated dates per day and excludes them (`NOT IN`) from the `DELETE` statement.

Comment: @3zzy Sorry, mySQL syntax is a little archaic for my liking :P
You will need to wrap the subquery further into an aliased table.
Ive updated the code so try that again

Answer (score 0):

Get the most recent time in a subquery, join that with the table, and delete.

```
DELETE i1 
FROM inventory AS i1
JOIN (SELECT DATE(updated) AS date, MAX(updated) AS latest
      FROM inventory
      WHERE itemname = '24T7351'
      GROUP BY date) AS i2 ON DATE(i1.updated) = i2.date AND i1.updated != i2.latest
WHERE itemname = '24T7351'
```

Comment: I don't really want the WHERE cause it can be any date. This query will basically keep the latest record for each day and delete the rest.

Comment: Forgot the FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest record on each date for each item:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM inventory i
WHERE i.updated < (select max(i2.updated)
                   from inventory i2
                   where i2.itemname = i.itemname and
                         date(i2.updated) = date(i.updated)
                  )
ORDER BY updated DESC;
```

Comment: he wants every record *except* the latest on each date.

Answer (score 0):

This solution would help you assign a rank to each of the rows. You can delete based on rank. The latest record has rank of 1.

```
SELECT
    ItemName,
    BLOCK_1_PRICE,
    M,
    S,
    B,
    P,
    updated,
    if (ItemName=@curItem,@curRank:= @curRank + 1, @curRank:=@reset) AS rank,
    @curItem:=ItemName,
    @curRank,
  @reset,
  @curItem
FROM
    inventory, (select @curRank:=1, @curItem:='NA', @reset:= 1) as r
ORDER BY 
    ItemName,updated DESC
```

If you want all records apart from the latest record, use the query as below. I would suggest that you create a new table with latest records, rather than deleting in the old table, if the inventory table is large. Link to SQLFiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb0a3d/20)

```
select * from 
(
SELECT
    ItemName,
    BLOCK_1_PRICE,
    M,
    S,
    B,
    P,
    updated,
    if (ItemName=@curItem,@curRank:= @curRank + 1, @curRank:=@reset) AS rank,
    @curItem:=ItemName,
    @curRank,
  @reset,
  @curItem
FROM
    inventory, (select @curRank:=1, @curItem:='NA', @reset:= 1) as r
ORDER BY 
    ItemName,updated DESC
  ) as t
  where rank > 1
```